# Trying to update ExtentReports from 2.x to 4.x

Tags: java, maven, selenium, extentreports

So basically I updated my ExtentReports dependency from 2.41.2 to 4.0.9, and needless to say that I had to change some stuff.
The only thing/line that is missing and giving me some trouble is this one, used in 2.41.2:

```
private static void setHtmlFile() {
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\ExtentReports\\";
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();//For reference
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
    String data = localDate.format(formatter);
    String fileName = "report" + Application.getInstance().getAppName() + data + ".html";
    extent = new ExtentReports(workingDir + fileName, true);
}
```

The last line "extent = new ExtentReports(workingDir + fileName, true);" gives me an error, "The constructor ExtentReports(String, boolean) is undefined".

I've tried going through the Documentation, but I can't find what I need to change.

Version 2
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/2/java/doc/

Version 4
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/4/java/javadoc/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your code for comparison between the old version and the new version.

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the OP and add the method